# How do you say 町 (in addresses) in English?

Tags: meaning, translation, words, terminology, daily-life

I know that in a normal context, 町 means town.

But I'm pretty sure it's different in Japanese addresses, where it typically goes like:

＿＿県＿＿市＿＿区＿＿町＿＿＿＿＿＿

I know that 県 means prefecture, 市 means city, and 区 means ward.

But how do you say 町 in English? I've been searching around and I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: I remember seeing "XXX-chō" on English maps, but I guess that's not a satisfying answer...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipalities_of_Japan#Non-municipality

Answer (score 6):

#### ＿都/道/府/県 ＿市 ＿区 ＿町

町 is just part of the name of an area in 市/区, so it can be written as `(-)cho` or `(-)machi` depending on its actual name. An area name does not always contain 町.

```
東京都町田市小山町（Oyamacho / Oyama-cho）
東京都町田市金森（Kanamori）
東京都千代田区一番町（Ichibancho / Ichiban-cho）
東京都千代田区飯田橋（Iidabashi）
大阪府大阪市中央区松屋町（Matsuyamachi / Matsuya-machi）
大阪府大阪市中央区北浜（Kitahama）
```

Note:

- 区 is only for the special wards of Tokyo (特別区 / 東京都区部 / 東京23区) and wards of designated cities (政令指定都市の行政区). Normal cities do not have 区.
- Each of the special wards of Tokyo is equivalent to a single city. Therefore it does not have 市 in its address name.

---

#### ＿都/道/府/県 ＿郡 ＿町

町 belonging to 郡 is an independent municipality in the same manner as 市 is, so you can call it a `town`. However, it is often written as `-cho` or `-machi` too.

```
神奈川県足柄下郡箱根町（Hakone Town / Hakone-machi）強羅（Goura）
愛知県海部郡蟹江町（Kanie Town / Kanie-cho）八幡（Hachiman）
愛知県海部郡蟹江町（Kanie Town / Kanie-cho）本町（Honmachi）
```

Some towns have 町 inside them like 蟹江町本町 above, but again they are just part of the names of smaller sections in towns.

Answer (score 3):

The suffix 町 "town" can be part of a place name, like 都・道・府・県 and 市・区. As a rule of thumb (for example in addresses), I would say 町 is *not* translated, but just transliterated as *-chō* or *-machi*, depending on the actual reading. That said, in some circumstances it may be translated (for example in fiction or, say, brochures for foreign residents), in which case *Town* seems to be standard, for example 平内町 *Hiranai Town*. (Similarly, 市 = City or 区 = Ward.)

If you want to look up the reading of a place name (for example if 町  is read *-chō* or *-machi*) a very convenient way is to use the website of the Post Office https://www.post.japanpost.jp/zipcode/. By the way, there seems to be a strong bias to either reading from prefecture to prefecture, for example 福岡県 has 1 *-chō* vs. 69 *-machi* whereas 北海道 has 1 *-machi* vs. 160 *-chō*.

For more info see also [@kaboc's excellent answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/76434/1628).

Comment: Good point. Similarly 村 also has both *mura* and *son*. Villages ending with *-son* only exist in 中国, 四国, 九州 and 沖縄 areas. http://www.kukanzeneki.net/omoituki/21/